# How do I obtain the characteristics and properties of an alloy?

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries, chemistry

I would like to obtain the characteristics and properties of the Alloy Chromel. How do I download that information from the database of Wolfram Alpha and then print it in a Mathematica Notebook?

---

Update

[image]

Comment: Seems obvious you should do what's suggested...You have a blocked activation key.

Comment: Seems obvious that I don't know how do I unblock the activation key

Comment: Ah, you need to contact wolfram, the error suggests this.

Comment: It does say "Please contact Wolfram" in the error message; that's not a problem anyone here on SE can take care of.

Comment: Are you using an illegally licensed version of Mathematica?

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the version you have, I'm running 11.2, you can type simply

```
=
```

or

```
==
```

note that just one or two equal signs, that will ask WA directly. Here is a blog post explaining the feature [from WA blog](http://blog.wolframalpha.com/2010/12/06/mathematica-becomes-a-wolframalpha-interface/)

[image: thing]

Comment: Equivalently, evaluate `WolframAlpha["chromel alloy properties"]`.

Comment: Yeah, I was doing that, but I have an error. I uploaded an imaging in my post showing it

Comment: @Delfin - code works fine for others. You need to contact Wolfram.